# I cannot find a way to extract underlined text, cant it be done with pdfminer.six?

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf, pdfminer, pdfplumber

I am trying to extract  a text in pdf which is underlined using python but not able to find a correct solution can anyone help on this, please

Comment: What hade you tried on your side before asking here?

Answer (score 0):

In a PDF there are no struck through or struck under fonts thus the best you could hope for is a flag at the start and end like in Rich Text. Commonly a line in paperspace is placed over/under the image / text characters. Often done later (like highlighting) as "Annotation" so you are looking for rectangles with narrow height.

PDFMiner 6 acknowledge they can at best close this issue. see https://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six/issues/237

You could look for StrikeThrough or StrikeUnder Annotation objects and a script showing how that may be done is available at https://github.com/0xabu/pdfannots